# Matching string/text values between 2 columns using R

Tags: r, matching

Hope everybody who reads this message is doing well :)

I am trying to identify the sellers who are reporting themselves as the buyers in a data set of 3M records. Therefore, I am trying to match the names in two different columns, column A = SellerName vs. column B = BuyerName. Column A names are cleaned and properly derived, but, column B contains raw data as reported by the sellers, so my goal is to use column A as the reference values and match them against column B, getting a boolean (TRUE or FALSE) as the result in a new column and accepting partial matches.

Dataset:

```
library(data.table)
    sales_table <- data.table(SellerName = c("Partner ABC INC", "Partner CPE Corp", "Partner TYS Ltd", "Partner MDW INC"), BuyerName = c("Subsidiary abc, Boston", "John Smith, CPA", "Tech tYs, East Coast", "partner mdw Inc"))
```

I tried this by using `str_detect()`, but it just returned the values in column A that are fully contained in column B:

```
sales_table_Mtchd <- sales_table %>%
mutate(Match = str_detect(sales_table$`BuyerName`, fixed(sales_table$`SellerName`, ignore_case = TRUE)))
```

Next, I include an example of what I am trying to get:

[expected outcome using R (full format)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHdLL.png)

```
*SellerName*        *BuyerName*              *Match*
Partner ABC INC     Subsidiary abc, Boston   TRUE
Partner CPE Corp    John Smith, CPA          FALSE
Partner TYS Ltd     Tech tYs, East Coast     TRUE
Partner MDW INC     partner mdw Inc          TRUE
```

I highly appreciate your help & tips in advance!!

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Done! Sorry, I am getting use to the forum rules :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `intersect`

```
require(tidyverse)
df = tibble(
    SellerName = c('Partner ABC INC', 'Partner CPE Corp', 'Partner TYS Ltd', 'Partner MDW INC'),
    BuyerName = c('Subsidiary abc, Boston', 'John Smith, CPA', 'Tech tYs, East Coast', 'partner mdw inc')
)

df_match = df %>% mutate(SellerName_ls = SellerName %>% tolower() %>% str_replace_all(',', '') %>% str_split(pattern = ' '),
              BuyerName_ls = BuyerName %>% tolower() %>% str_replace_all(',', '') %>% str_split(pattern = ' '))

df_match$match_string = map2(df_match$SellerName_ls, df_match$BuyerName_ls, intersect) %>% map_chr(str_c, collapse = ' ')

df_match = df_match %>% mutate(matched = ifelse(str_length(match_string) > 0, T, F))
```

Comment: Hey buddy, thanks a lot for your quick response! Just a quick question, where did you define 'match_string'?

Comment: Nevermind, it was a typo I made. Thank you so very much!!